# です after a verb (しまうでしょう) in lyrics

Tags: grammar, verbs

In the lyrics[[1](https://utaten.com/lyric/mi23012412/)] of 月と水鏡 by 横山由依, I realized the phrase 誰か傷つけてしまうでしょう. I first thought it was a mistranscription of ～しまう**ん**でしょう, but you can clearly hear しまうでしょう in the actual song ([1:27](https://youtu.be/q94eoSRftw8?t=87)). Could you explain what this is?

Comment: です and だ after verbs is very unusual but だろう and でしょう are completely normal, and mean something different from what 傷つけてしまいましょう would mean

Answer (score 1):

です and だ can **never** go with verbs, as they only go with nouns and adjectives. However, でしょう and だろう **can** go directly after verbs to add uncertainty. でしょう is not bound by the same grammatical constraints of です.